# HTML Select Multiple with Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

We are currently creating a drop down in Laravel like so:

```
{{Form::select('job_location_id', 
                        $jobLocationList, 
                        '',
                        ['class' => 'form-control', 
                        'autocomplete' => 'off']
                        )}}
```

Is it possible to make this a "Select Multiple" with Laravel?

Comment: That last array parameter is really just a list of attributes to put on the element.  You can put anything in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ Form::select('job_location_id[]', $jobLocationList, '', [
    'class'        => 'form-control',
    'multiple'     => 'multiple',
    'autocomplete' => 'off'
]) }}
```

Comment: Oh my god worked perfectly! How do i give you 1,000 pts?

Comment: Haha. Accepting the answer is more than enough, trust me :)

Comment: Yes it makes me wait wait 15 minutes before I can lol. Okay the only thing i changed was select('job_location_id' to select('job_location_id[]' and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, yes, you'd need that, wouldn't you? Haha. Updated my answer as well.